# jquery display element issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have implemented jquery on the site (click on the plus sign)
http://pligg.marsgibson.info
Issue is on page loads its first showing the summary and then hiding it

I also put 
display none; to my style.css
.toggle_container

but doing this fully hide the summary ( which I want to show on clicking plus sign )
here is the link to jquery
http://pligg.marsgibson.info/templates/wistie/js/toggle.js
what could be possible fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
dd { display: none; }
```

dd is not a class therefore .dd will not work. Probably safer to target .headline dd for a more precise hiding in case you want to use dd else where

```
.headline dd { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to hide in css that  `$('dd').hide();` and not js. Because js is slow, and takes some time to hide the element

ex:

```
.dd{
 display:none;
}
```